# Synonym-ize [sum] into [worksheet-function]

Tags: support, tag-synonym-request

There are 35 questions with [sum](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sum) and only [one](https://superuser.com/questions/735892/bash-sum-average-numbers-in-files) that isn't about a spreadsheet application. I suggested the synonym for [worksheet-function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) because I don't find [sum](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sum) to be very useful. If it goes through, the [bash question](https://superuser.com/questions/735892/bash-sum-average-numbers-in-files) should be retagged.

While I was at it, I also suggested [array-formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/array-formulas) be a synonym as they are a subset of [worksheet-function](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function). Feel free to disagree with this one if you find it useful.

### Edit

[Link to voting page](https://superuser.com/tags/worksheet-function/synonyms)

Comment: It seems to me that sum is a classic meta tag and we should just kill it off. I'll look up the other tag when i get home

Comment: I went ahead and removed [sum] from the bash question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been remapped. Status - completed, please.